# Помогите пожалуйста с ошибкой ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2570)

Tags: python-3.x, openssl

Я начинающий программист, я начал делать телеграм бота на python с библиотекой telebot, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что когда я начал тестировать бота с нескольких устройств одновременно бот остановился и выдал ошибку

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/bar_5237_bot/bar_bot.py", line 71, in start
    self.user_data.set_id(id)
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/bar_5237_bot/utils/user_data.py", line 25, in set_id
    self.save_all_data()
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/bar_5237_bot/utils/user_data.py", line 72, in save_all_data
    self.google_sheets_api.update_user_data(user_info)
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/bar_5237_bot/google/google_sheets_api.py", line 139, in update_user_data
    body=body
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 932, in execute
    headers=self.headers,
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 225, in request
    **kwargs
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey,
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1396, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1373, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 319, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 280, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2570)
```

как это можно исправить? Если информации не достаточно, то спрашивайте.